# Imports not resolving in generated GraphQL queries with Apollo3

Tags: kotlin, graphql, apollo, kotlin-multiplatform

I've noticed that when I generate class files from GraphQL queries, the imports for Apollo3 aren't resolving. See the screenshot below.

I'm using the Apollo3 GraphQL library in a [Kotlin Multiplatform](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform.html) project. The Apollo [Get Started With Multiplatform](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/android/essentials/get-started-multiplatform/) docs are pretty confusing and I may have my project configured incorrectly.

I can download the schema, and generate the files without a problem.

**./build.gradle.kts**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.21")
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0")
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete::class) {
    delete(rootProject.buildDir)
}
```

**./shared/build.gradle.kts**

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.KotlinNativeTarget

plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    id("com.android.library")
    id("com.apollographql.apollo3").version("3.0.0-alpha03")
}

kotlin {
    android()

    val iosTarget: (String, KotlinNativeTarget.() -> Unit) -> KotlinNativeTarget =
        if (System.getenv("SDK_NAME")?.startsWith("iphoneos") == true)
            ::iosArm64
        else
            ::iosX64

    iosTarget("ios") {
        binaries {
            framework {
                baseName = "shared"
            }
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("com.apollographql.apollo:apollo-runtime-kotlin:2.5.7")
            }
        }
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test-common"))
                implementation(kotlin("test-annotations-common"))
            }
        }
        val androidMain by getting
        val androidTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test-junit"))
                implementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
            }
        }
        val iosMain by getting
        val iosTest by getting
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion(30)
    sourceSets["main"].manifest.srcFile("src/androidMain/AndroidManifest.xml")
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion(23)
        targetSdkVersion(30)
    }
}
```

[image: Unresolved references]

Comment: D'oh! I found the answer. It was misconfigured gradle. I'll post an answer tomorrow with the details.

Comment: Hey what was the issue?

Comment: Seriously, how about sharing the solution after posting a question to the community?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue. In my case, it was fixed by making sure the runtime dep is using the same version as the apollo plugin applied (3.0.0-alpha03).

So try changing the content in `./shared/build.gradle.kts` file, replacing this line

```
implementation("com.apollographql.apollo:apollo-runtime-kotlin:2.5.7")
```

with

```
implementation("com.apollographql.apollo:apollo-runtime-kotlin:3.0.0-alpha03")
```